# Index Exponent with LaTeX

Tags: subscripts, superscripts

Please, how can i write

```
C i,j
```

in LaTeX (`i` as an index and `j` an an exponent)?

I know just that:

```
C^j
C_i
```

Comment: Do you just want `C_i^j`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can add a subscript and a superscript in sequence: `$C_a^b$`. If you need more than one character in a sub- or superscript, use braces. Thus, `$C_{ab}$` produces a subscript `ab`, and `$C_{a^b}$` produces a subscript `a` which itself has a superscript `b`.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\begin{document}
\[ C_a^b \quad C_{ab} \quad C_{a^b} \]
\end{document}
```

[image: subscripts]

(I used `a` and `b` because the last example doesn't work very well with `i` and `j` in the default font).